# List records where IDs match from two seperate tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables in my database, one (table 1) which is for users which includes: ID, firstname, lastname, login and password. the other table (table2) has the data in it, which also has an ID field. i want to know how i only display the data in table 2, when the ID of table 2 = the ID of table 1.

i think i need to add to the below parameter, but unsure of how to do it

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage WHERE completed= 'no'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

any clarification please let me know and thanks

Page of code which list the data from table 2

```
require_once('auth.php');

 $host="*"; // Host name 
 $username="*"; // Mysql username 
 $password="*"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="*"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="*"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM Triage WHERE completed= 'no'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

 ?>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="1270" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="1270"><table width="1270" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="400"><p align="center"><strong>List of patients for triage</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="70" align="center"><strong>Reference</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Forename</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Surname</strong></td>
        <td width="100" align="center"><strong>DOB</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Mobile Number</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Home Number</strong></td>
        <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Date of Call</strong></td>
        <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Time of call</strong></td>
        <td width="100" align="center"><strong>Physio ID</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Triage completed</strong></td>
        <td width="120" align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
      <tr>
        <td><? echo $rows['Reference']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['Forename']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['surname']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['DOB']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['Mobile']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['Home']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['Date']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['Time']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['PhysioID']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['completed']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="update.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ? >">update</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>
  <?php
 mysql_close();
 ?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Update

```
//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login-form.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: member-index.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login-failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is totally outdated these days. Consider updating your code to keep on track...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `INNER JOIN` (when table1 and table2 are 1:1), or `LEFT JOIN` (when table 1 and table2 are 1:n)

```
$sql="
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM Triage t1
  INNER JOIN members t2 ON (t2.PhysioID = t1.member_id)
  WHERE t1.completed = 'no'
";
```

**EDITED #1:**

```
$sql="
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM Triage t1
  INNER JOIN members t2 ON (t2.PhysioID = t1.member_id)
  WHERE t1.completed = 'no' AND t1.member_id = ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."
";
```

And in `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` will be ID of your logged user.

**EDITED #2:**

```
$sql="
  SELECT t2.*
  FROM Triage t1
  INNER JOIN members t2 ON (t2.PhysioID = t1.member_id)
  WHERE t1.completed = 'no' AND t1.member_id = ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."
";
```

Comment: $sql="
      SELECT t1.*, t2.*
      FROM Triage t1
      INNER JOIN members t2 ON (t2.PhysioID = t1.member_id)
      WHERE t1.completed= 'no'
    ";

would this be right? i have changed all the fields to the correct ones.

Comment: this worked after i changed the fields around, but i have a login page where a member will login and i only want to show the data that = their id? do you want to see the sucessful login scrpt?---- so the PhysioID will be a field in the data table and the member_ID will be in the table with the member's data.

Comment: where would i add this mate? i have added the login script as an update to the oringal question

Comment: So why you just dont select from the `members` table, when you dont need data from `Triage` table? See my two edits in my answer...

Comment: i had to change t1.member_id to t2.PhysioID but what you put worked. the ".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']." already = t1.member_id
many thanks for your help- greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to join data from table1 and table2 using SQL JOIN expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  table2 
  JOIN table1 
    ON table1.id=table2.id 
WHERE completed= 'no'
```

There are various kind of JOINs (left join, cross join...) - look it up.

Comment: thanks guys this also worked but the issue i have now is that i only need the data from table 2 displayed which the physioID = member_id  whos logged in.

e.g.(table 1) luke - 1 = member_ID -  this is who is logged in
(table 2) the PhysioID = 1 - i only want to display this field and non of the other fields